# Strange anomalies with weight painting

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I've been trying to create a rig for my dragon character and I'm doing weight painting right now. However, some strange anomalies keep getting on my way.

[Picture of the anomaly is too big and so I've added it as a link instead](https://gyazo.com/56f9116d2a633a68c9f86ae094c2eeff)

When I select the vertex group of the bone, it can be seen that there are no other vertices selected on the other leg, which makes it really hard to understand. 
[image]

Here's the same picture in weight paint mode and none vertices of the other leg are affected by the paint..
[image]

Comment: Problably a rotation problem. Blender knows how to mirror on X for the armature. Face your model and armature to -Y in object mode. Then apply rotation on both (ctrl+A and rotation).

Comment: The problem is that I am not trying to mirror weight paint. It's moving the vertices itself. ...Or I am misunderstanding you..
There' s a topology mirror to solve that problem anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the gif, at least two other bones are moving when you move that shin bone. The most likely explanation for your issue is that you have parts of the other leg weighted to one of these bones.

Edit:
Another thing you could try is to set the armature modifier to deform the edit mode mesh, pose it so you get the deformed mesh and enter edit mode.
From there, select one or the deformed verts and open the right hand panel in the 3d view ('N' panel). One of the sections there lists all the vertex groups and their weights that apply to that vertex. This should help you track down where the problematic weighting is coming from.

Comment: It's weird...
I checked every bone manually - looked whether there' s weight paint on the other leg and also looked for the vertex groups. There were no other vertices in the vertex groups.

I also tried to use the "Clean" weight tool for some bones. It didn' t solve the problem...

Comment: @TheLast_BlenderBender updated my answer with a way to help track down errant weights. Try that and see what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem seemed to be in the "X mirror -> Topology Mirror" option. I don' t know... I had it on earlier, but it didn' t affect my mesh earlier.. I think my model truly is facing the wrong axis to make Topology Mirror option work, just as "Lemon" said in the comments. Anyways big thanks for this.. Your tip made me discover the problem :)